# Where i can store multiple NSMutableArray in One Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have five NSMutableArray each NSMutableArray holding another object array ...I want to store all five NSMutableArray in one array...How can i do this?

```
    NSMutableArray *mA1 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *mA2 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *mA3 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *mA4 = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *mA5 = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And after store all five NSMutableArray in one array ..how can i retrieve NSMutableArray from that array ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in a `for` cycle, no need to write that repeating code with 5 instantiations:

```
NSMurableArray *container = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
     [container addObject:[NSMutableArray new]];
}
```

Then access them by `container[2]`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *mA1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA2 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA3 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA4 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA5 = [NSMutableArray array];


NSArray *combinedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mA1,mA2,mA3,mA4,mA5,nil];

or
NSArray *combinedArray = @[mA1,mA2,mA3,mA4,mA5]; //immutable
NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [@[mA1,mA2,mA3,mA4,mA5]mutableCopy]; // mutable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
First add all your 5 array into NSMutableArray say "mainArray" like this

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutablearray alloc]initWithObjects:mA1,mA2,mA3,mA4,mA5,nil];
```

this will add all 5 arrays into main array. Now to retrieve them back from array you can do like this

```
NSMutablearray *array = [mainArray objectAtIndex:0];//here pass index of array you want to get
```

or you use for loop to iterate all array from the mainArray..
Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *mA1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA2 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA3 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA4 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *mA5 = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *yourArray = @[mA1, mA2, mA3, mA4, mA5];//yourArray store all five NSMutableArray

for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.count; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *mA = array[i];//mA is the NSMutableArray(mA1 or other).
}
```

Comment: where did you reference array?

Comment: @Joshua you mean reference ```yourArray```? I foget to rename it. Now I have fixed it.